# Como contar os zeros à direita de um número?

Tags: matemática, independente-de-linguagem

Tenho um número, `nnnnn000`. Devo contar quantos zeros **à direita** tem esse numero.

Casos de teste:

- 123000 números zeros 3
- 102030 números zeros 1

Aberto a sugestões!

Comment: Quer resposta em todas essas linguagens?

Comment: Escolha melhor a linguagem, senão complica. Cada uma tem um jeito diferente.

Comment: Sim..será muito interessante ter varias respostas!

Comment: Poder ser inicialmente a linguagem C.

Comment: Mas torna a pergunta ampla demais. Talvez focando a duvida uma linguagem por vez seja mais interessante.

Comment: Acho que esse tipo de coisa combina mais com o Rosetta Code, mas se alguém se aventurar a responder, pra mim tá bom. Cada um pode postar na linguagem que conhece.

Comment: Pronto alterado para linguagem C ou JAVA. Alguma resposta ?

Comment: Como utilizar o resettacode.org ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva só comentei como exemplo

Comment: @Bacco, como fiz uma resposta em Groovy, você acha prudente colocar a tag Grooyv na pergunta?

Comment: @cantoni eu acho que você pode começar a resposta dizendo "Só pra complementar, como a pergunta original pedia em várias linguagens, segue uma versão em Groovy". Acho melhor do que enchermos de tag. UPDATE: Agora que eu vi que vc fez exatamente isso. Acho que já basta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seria isto:

```
int countZeros(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n % 10 == 0) {
        count++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Em C: Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1NXzmD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hpiqyeyz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountDigits.c).

Em Java: Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gT37fY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gaakyqlo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/CountDigits.java).

Obviamente pode ser melhorado, como por por exemplo pode validar a entrada de dados da função. Preferi deixar simples já que a pergunta não fala nada sobre isto e pode ficar como um exercício para o AP.

Comment: ótimo...resolveu perfeitamente o problema. Parabéns!

Comment: @alexjosesilva Só um aviso: passar `0` para o método vai resultar num erro de divisão. Isso não é estritamente necessário para a lógica, mas já vi professores descontarem nota por causa desse detalhe. Inclusive eles gostam de "pegar" alunos durante apresentações de trabalho pedindo para digitar valores negativos e zeros só para ver o que acontece. Eu mesmo sou culpado disso. :D

Comment: Hum...comentário pertinente @utluiz

Answer (score 11):

Nos comentários da pergunta foi sugerido que a resposta fosse dada em qualquer linguagem. Então para acrescentar deixo um exemplo em [Groovy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/groovy/info):

Exemplo com 7 zeros

```
def numero = 2220002330000000
assert numero==0?0:numero.toString().reverse().takeWhile{it=='0'}.size() == 7
```

Exemplo com nenhum zero

```
def numero = 222000233
assert numero==0?0:numero.toString().reverse().takeWhile{it=='0'}.size() == 0
```

Explicando o código:

Primeiro (como observado pelo @utluiz), é preciso testar se o número é == `0`, caso seja, é preciso retornar 0 e não 1 (como na versão original). Pra isso, um `se` ternário é feito.

Se for diferente de `0`, então o numero é convertido para String. Logo em seguida a string é invertida. A *closure* `takeWhile` monta uma lista onde cada elemento será um `'0'`. A `takeWhile` vai interromper quando o primeiro caracter que não for um zero for encontrado. Finalmente, chama-se o método `size()` para contar quantos elementos a lista possui (ou seja, quantos zeros foram encontrados à direita).

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/E3pq2G)

Você pode até mesmo injetar um método chamado `contaZerosDireita` na classe Integer ou Long, veja como:

```
Long.metaClass.contaZerosDireita {
    return delegate==0?0:delegate.toString().reverse().takeWhile{it=='0'}.size()
}
```

Para usar basta simplesmente fazer isso:

```
def numero = 2220002330000000
println numero.contaZerosDireita()
```

ou diretamente

```
println 2220002330000000.contaZerosDireita()
```

Comment: Estou feliz com sua iniciativa @cantoni...

Comment: Obrigado, @alexjosesilva. O objetivo da minha resposta é apenas apresentar uma forma diferente em Groovy. Ao explicar o código eu consigo passar um pouco das funcionalidades da linguagens (como as Closures, por exemplo).

Comment: Se passar somente `0` vai retornar `1`, certo? Acho que precisa de um teste a mais.

Comment: Obrigado @utluiz, versão corrigida a partir da sua observação.

Answer (score 8):

## Versão em Java

```java
byte rightZeros(long n) {
    for (byte z = 0; ; z++, n /= 10) {
        if (n < 10 || n % 10 != 0) return z;
    }
}
```

#### [Código no IdeOne](https://ideone.com/jjhWWp)

## Versão em Python

```python
def right_zeros(n):
    z = 0
    while True:
        n, r = divmod(n, 10)
        if n == 0 or r != 0:
            return z
        z += 1

print(right_zeros(123000))
print(right_zeros(102030))
print(right_zeros(123123))
```

Considerações:

- `divmod` retorna tanto o resultado quanto o resto da divisão numa tupla

#### [Código no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/FNIvlC)

## Versão em Clojure

```clj
(defn right_zeros
  [np]
    (loop [z 0 n np]
        (if (or (< n 10) (not= (mod n 10) 0))
            z
            (recur (inc z) (/ n 10)))))

(println (right_zeros 123000))
(println (right_zeros 102030))
(println (right_zeros 123123))
```

Considerações:

- Linha 1: declara uma função
- Linha 2: parâmetro `np`
- Linha 3: declara um laço com dois parâmetros:

  1. `z` com o valor inicial `0`
  2. `n` com o valor inicial de `np`
- Linha 4: verifica se o número `n` é menor que `10` ou se o resto da divisão é diferente de zero

  - Linha 5: se o teste acima for verdadeiro, retorna `z`
  - Linha 6: executa se o teste acima for falso e como laços em linguagens baseadas no Lisp são feitas usando recursão, então ele basicamente usa o `recur` para voltar ao início do laço incrementando `z` e dividindo `n` por `10`.

#### [Código no IdeOne](https://ideone.com/ZYOudr)

Answer (score 8):

## Versão em Haskell :)

```
countZerosDireita :: Int -> Int
countZerosDireita = length . takeWhile (==0) . reverse . map (read . (:[])) . show
```

- `show` converte o número para String (lista de Char).
- `map (read . (:[]))` transforma a String em uma lista de Int.
- `reverse` inverte a lista de Int (de forma que o número 120 original vire [0,2,1]).
- `takeWhile (==0)` pega todos os Int da lista enquanto eles forem `0`.
- `length` retorna o tamanho da lista que contém apenas `0`.

Comment: `:[]` -- POS: programação orientada a smiles. :D

Comment: /\ HHAHAAH, boaa @utluiz

Comment: hahah, programando nem percebi. Haskell == smiles!

Answer (score 5):

```
loop{
  divide por 10 e soma 1 no contador se n%10 == 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Versão em PHP

```
function contarZeros($n) {
    $count = 0;
    while ($n % 10 == 0) {
        $count++;
        $n /= 10;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

---

## Versão em C#

```
public static int ContarZeros(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n % 10 == 0) {
        count++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

[C# Ideone](https://ideone.com/kmJJKd)

Só para constar :)

Answer (score 2):

### Versão em JavaScript (ES6) com RegExp:

```
const contarZeros = (numero) => /0*$/.exec(numero)[0].length;
```

Comment: Gabriel, Cool! (+1)

Comment: @JJoao valeu, dei uma editada, achei um jeito melhor ;)

Answer (score 1):

Versão em pseudocódigo:

```
function contar-zeros (numero conta)
    if numero = 0
        return 1
    else-if (mod numero 10) = 0
       contar-zeros (numero / 10), (conta + 1) //Recursiva
    else
       return conta
```

Versão em `Common Lisp` para explanação:

```
(defun contar-zeros (num &optional (count 0))
   (cond ((= 0 num) 1) 
         ((= 0 (mod num 10)) (contar-zeros (/ num 10) (1+ count)))
         (t count)))
```

A maioria das linguagens da programação traca numeros como `000` por `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo entradas a ser um número por linha, seguem 4 soluções *oneliners* um pouco maquiavélicas.

### Versão Perl 1

```
perl -nE '/\d(0*)\b/g and say length($1)'
```

Explicação

```
para cada linha ∈ texto                     ⎪    perl -n
 ⎧ procura zeros no final de uma palavra    ⎪      /\d(0*)\b/g
 ⎪                                          ⎪      and
 ⎩ escreve o comprimento da string match $1 ⎪      say length($1)'
```

### Versão Perl 2, 3

```
perl -nE  'say log(s/\d*[1-9]/1/r)/log(10)'
perl -nlE 'say length( s/\d*[1-9]//r )'
```

### Versão Awk

```
awk -F'[^0]' '{print length($NF)}'
```

ou seja:

- separador de campo é tudo menos zero   `awk -F'[^0]'`
- para cada linha, imprimir o comprimento do ultimo campo `length($NF)`

Answer (score 0):

## Versão em Python 3

```
def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
   count = 0
   while num % 10 == 0:
      count += 1
      num /=  10
      if num == 0:
         count = 1
         return count
   return count
```